# Custom Tabs Not Working

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am trying to add a list of postcodes to my DocuSign document but it seems to be stopping any tabs from showing. The only other tab is the setSignHereTabs tab shown in the PHP SDK on GitHub.

```
// add postcode tab
$postcodeTab = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
$postcodeTab->setDocumentId = ("1");
$postcodeTab->setRecipientId = ("1");
$postcodeTab->setPageNumber = ("1");
$postcodeTab->setName = ("postcodes");
$postcodeTab->setTabLabel = ("ReadOnlyDataField");
$postcodeTab->setValue = ($postcodes);
$postcodeTab->setLocked = ("true");
$postcodeTab->setXPosition = ("100");
$postcodeTab->setYPosition = ("100"); 
// add the postcode tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setTextTabs(array($postcodeTab));
```

I am using the Rest Api documentation and "Datafields" section via the link below as a guide:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

No error is showing in the Apache error log. Any help would be appreciated.

GitHub Link

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client

Rest Api Docs

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/

Comment: This might be a question for their support team to answer. Also, why do you surround your strings with redundant parenthesis `(` and `)`?

Comment: I was just keeping it in line with what was shown here:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php

Comment: @Cozmoz .. [DocuSign PHP client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client) uses the Rest Api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be accessing the function, instead of setting it:

```
$postcodeTab->setDocumentId = ("1")
```

Should be:

```
$postcodeTab->setDocumentId("1")
```

`setDocumentId` is a **function** in the instance `DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text`. When you put an equal sign, `setDocumentId` gets overwritten and just becomes a string of "1", which essentially does nothing. You'll have to update each reference, and remove the equal signs before it, so you're actually calling each function which will set the respective fields internally to the instance.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked but now the signature box is not showing.

Comment: That's another issue, and another question. Either edit your original question, and include more information and post another one with the current issue you're having